# How do I address custom view class from Activity?

Tags: java, android

I made a custom view which I called Game.java

```
public class Game extends View {
    public Game(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
//here goes class
public void shot(){
}
//method I want to use sometime
}
```

here's part of my layout file for Activity game.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/root"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".GameActivity" >

    <com.vladdrummer.textmaster.Game
        android:id="@+id/game"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />
<View
        android:id="@+id/spareview"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

etc..
So, in Activity I simply do

```
setContentView(R.layout.game);
```

and I got my custom View class called Game.java as the part of the screen

But how do I address it? if I do :

```
Game game;
game =(Game) findViewById(R.id.game);
game.shot();
```

it crashes.

of course , I can do :

```
 Game game=new Game(this)
 setContentView(game);
```

and have access to game so it won't crash, but I need other elements on screen as well

please tell me how to do it right

Comment: what error do you get when you reference from xml??

Comment: Does "findViewById(R.id.game)" return null? Or is the crash from within game.shot()?

Comment: try to use all constructors in your GameView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` in your xml and place it anywhere you want. You can have other views in xml also. This is one way

```
setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout); // infalte layout
RelativeLayout rl =(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);// initialize 
Game game=new Game(this);
rl.addView(game);  // ad view to container
```

But you have the custom view in your layout. You are missing constructors in `GameView`. Your method  also should also work

Read Chapter 4 Creating user Interface by Retro Meier Professional Android Devleopment

Comment: it's just a simplified example. I don't want to post all the code, the code here is not the point. Thank you for the answer, I'll try it

Comment: @user2976267 but the code is relevant and you should post the relevant code also.

Comment: @user2976267 i am saying it bcoz your method also should work. is your package name right for the cusotm view in xml??